# What’s the use of the coroutines dependencies on an Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies, kotlin-coroutines

My question is what’s the use of the coroutines dependencies on an Android app?

Specifically the following dependency that is mentioned in the Android Developers [site](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines#dependency)

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'
```

(or the newer version `1.6.4`)

Seems to me that everything that is related to coroutines, works fine even without this dependency. So what is the purpose of adding this dependency to an Android project?

The rest of the dependencies of the Android project

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0-alpha02"
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Comment: paste here more information, because there are libraries in android with already included dependencies for coroutines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for your information: coroutines are already included in libraries:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'){
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx', module: 'kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm'
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx', module: 'kotlinx-coroutines-android'
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx', module: 'kotlinx-coroutines-core'
    }
    //implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0' <- include coroutines
    //implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4' <- include coroutines
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
}
```

That's why you see and can use coroutines features.

Comment: The term is "transitive dependency". The dependencies of your dependencies are included in your project automatically.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines#android):

> This gives you access to the Android `Dispatchers.Main` coroutine dispatcher and also makes sure that in case of a crashed coroutine with an unhandled exception that this exception is logged before crashing the Android application, similarly to the way uncaught exceptions in threads are handled by the Android runtime.

So if you don't use `Dispatchers.Main` and don't want exceptions to be logged, you can remove this dependency. And make sure to test the app after removing it.

Comment: I do have access to `Dispatchers.Main` without the dependencies! I haven't checked the logging of the exceptions, but since I do have access to `Dispatchers.Main`, seems that the docs are not accurate.

Comment: Hm, yeah, it's interesting.... Maybe after removing the dependency, cleaning up the project. invalidating caches and restarting Android Studio the using of `Dispatchers.Main` will be highlighted with red color and project will not compile, but this is only my guess. Or perhaps another dependency includes this one and you don't need to add it explicitly.

Comment: I did exactly that (clear project, invalidate cache, restart the project) and everything runs as it should without the forementioned dependencies.  `Dispatchers.Main` is NOT highlighted in red. "...Or perhaps another dependency includes this one" that was exactly my question. Is the coroutines dependencies included in some other dependency? Which one? If not, what's the purpose of the coroutines dependency?

Comment: There is another answer, that it is used in `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` library, but I can't confirm this.

Comment: Hi @Serrgio, Can you please help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75367786/8266651).

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding another answer because this is a broader issue with Android libraries in general, not just the coroutines library, so you need to be mindful of it. The libraries you use have their *own* dependencies, so they pull in certain versions of *other* libraries that they require.

These additional dependencies are called *transitive dependencies*, and it's why you can use e.g. `LiveData` without adding the `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx` package - it's because something else is pulling in a version of that library, e.g. the `activity` library. You'll often see these dependency versions mentioned in the changelogs for a library, [like this `activity` one](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.5.1):

> **Version 1.5.1**
>
> July 27, 2022
>
> **Dependency update**
>
> - The `Activity` library now depends on the Lifecycle `2.5.1`.

What this means is using version *1.5.1* of the `activity` library will pull in version *2.5.1* of the `lifecycle` libraries. That's the most recent dependency version bump, so that goes for the newer versions of `activity` too.

---

But often those transitive dependencies will be outdated - libraries usually won't *require* new versions of another dependency unless they've made significant changes that require an upgrade. Generally, they're not requiring the most recent versions of other libraries.

**This means if you want to use newer versions of those libraries, you need to explicitly add them as dependencies yourself**. For a long time, `activity` would pull in a really old version of `lifecycle` - if you wanted to use the newer features, you had to import `lifecycle` yourself, using the version number you wanted. When a dependency is declared multiple times with different versions, [Gradle picks the highest version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#sub:resolution-strategy) (unless you explicitly take steps to prevent that).

If you want to see the dependency tree for your app, you can run the `dependencies` Gradle task - it'll show you what dependencies each library requests, their version numbers, and whether they're the version that's ultimately being selected or if they're being superseded by another declaration elsewhere in the tree. You can do that with this button in the Gradle window:

[image: The Gradle toolbar with the "run task" button highlighted]

and running `gradle app:dependencies` (or using `gradlew` from the command line). There's some info about interpreting the output [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html).